# Blocking node from reading simultaneously from db

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a set of values in a mongoDB I need to only be read ones. So when I have read them I delete that line from the DB. But since node is async if I do getValue() twice in quick succession I get the same value, since the DB has not had time to delete the old one. Does anyone know a good way to fix this problem. I can think of a couple but nothing good.

I don’t have my code here so just wrote a quick example to show my problem.

```
Var getValue = function() {
  ReadfromDB(function(data){
       deleteRecord(); // show that what we read has been updated
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. The reading is placed into a promise that's done when the deleting is done as well. This can stack so if you do `getValue()` 20 times it still should execute in the correct order.

```
var getValue = function(){
    var currentPromise;
    var read = function(){
        return ReadfromDB().then(function(data){
           deleteRecord(); // show that what we read has been updated
        });
    }
    return function() {
        if(currentPromise){
            currentPromise = currentPromise.then(read)
        }else{
            currentPromise = read();
        }
    }
}
```

What you need to do outside this code is make sure `ReadfromDB` returns a promise object.

Comment: Thanks but I'm haveing a hard time reading this code, never worked with promise. So what i think it does: The first time you read it just sets up and returns. The next time you get the value from last time. Am I on to something?

Comment: Basically yes, the first time it runs and *returns a promise*, the second time it already has a promise and executes in the `then` method, meaning, it executes when the previous function was 'done'. Give this a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thanks :) I'll play with it when I get home :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use case for a closure!

```
var getValue = (function() {
  var called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      ReadFromDB(function(data) {
        deleteRecord();
      });
    }
  };
}());
```

---

You could also use [once](https://www.npmjs.org/package/once) to do exactly the same thing.

```
var once = require('once');

var getValue = once(function() {
  ReadFromDB(function(data) {
    deleteRecord();
  });
});
```